# Android: Linear Layout with Search TExt and Toggle Button on one line

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I have a horizontal `LinearLayout` containing a text box (search) and a toggle button. How can I get the search box to fill all the width less the width of a toggle box?

Visually:
[Wide Search Box][Toggle]

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/search_box"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="type to search titles"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:capitalize="none"
            android:linksClickable="false"
            android:autoLink="none"
            android:autoText="true"
            android:singleLine="true" />
        <ToggleButton
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/toggleButton1"
            android:textOff="ABC"
            android:textOn="KMs" />
    </LinearLayout
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `layout_weight` attribute to the `EditText`, such as:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/search_box"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:hint="type to search titles"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:capitalize="none"
        android:linksClickable="false"
        android:autoLink="none"
        android:autoText="true"
        android:singleLine="true" />
    <ToggleButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/toggleButton1"
        android:textOff="ABC"
        android:textOn="KMs" />
</LinearLayout
```

I also modified the `layout_width` attributes, so the button wraps to it's content and the text field fills the remaining space on the line.  Adding weight to a child in a `LinearLayout` tells it to take up the remaining space, and the value of the weight determines how it will do so.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by using `layout:weight`:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/search_box"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:hint="type to search titles"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:capitalize="none"
        android:linksClickable="false"
        android:autoLink="none"
        android:autoText="true"
        android:singleLine="true" />
    <ToggleButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/toggleButton1"
        android:textOff="ABC"
        android:textOn="KMs" />
</LinearLayout
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `android:layout_width` of the ToggleButton to `wrap_content`

Answer (score 0):

Simply change your EditText **layout_width** to 0dp
and add the **layout_weight** attribute:

```
android:layout_weight="1"
```

and your **layout_width** of ToggleButton must be set to **wrap_content**

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```